# How to provide | revoke access to an AWS machine without going through the AWS console

Tags: account-security, aws

Assuming if you do via SSH (which is shared among multiple team members), how to manage this from a security perspective or should each user be given a separate SSH key

Comment: This question seems incomplete to me - did you mean *"Assuming **control** ... via SSH*? If this is the case, I think you have literally answered your own question: Can we manage this from a security persepective? What should we do? *A: Give each user a separate SSH key*. Here's a discussion on the topic: https://serverfault.com/q/300352 and wrt. AWS EC2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html